# Is it necessary to close an InputStreamReader in a BufferedReader

Tags: java, inputstreamreader

We all know that it is a good habit to close all the StreamReaders we have defined at the end of code.

Now we can see that **two Readers** was defined as below. BufferedReader and InputStreamReader.The BufferedReader was closed, but we are unable to close the InputStreamReader.

**JAVA code:**

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    connection.getInputStream()));
if (in != null) {
    in.close();
    }
```

The problem is here, if the InputStreamReader in the parentheses should be closed? Will this kind of code bring some problem to the program? Please tell me , thank you~

Comment: http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2011/03/java-7-try-with-auto-closable-resources/

Comment: If you take a look at the [JavaDocs for `BufferedReader#close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#close()), you will see it says *"Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it. Once the stream has been closed, further read(), ready(), mark(), reset(), or skip() invocations will throw an IOException. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect."*, which basically means that calling `close` on `BufferedReader` will close any associated (child) streams

Comment: This question is under discussion on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319744/why-was-this-question-deleted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with doing this, in fact the [`InputStreamReader` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) from the Java API does it.

In this case, the `InputStreamReader` is being used by the `BufferedReader`, which means they will both close when the `BufferedReader` [`close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#close()) function is called as it: *"Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it."* As the `InputStreamReader` is also very clearly *"associated"* with the stream, it too will be closed.

When you build a `BufferedReader` using an `InputStreamReader` this way, they really are the same reader bundled together, not two different readers.

Answer (score 6):

It's important to close any resource that you use.

`in.close` will close BufferedReader, which in turn closes the resources that it itself uses ie. the InputStreamReader.

So what you are doing will be closing both of them assuming no exception occurs before you call `in.close`.

To ensure that it is closed no matter what use `try-with-resources` it will automatically close it for you once your block is done or when an exception occurs.

You can do it like this:

```
try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
connection.getInputStream()))){/*code here*/}
```

All the resources in the `try()` are guranteed to be closed.

Comment: Yes, but the question is, does the OP need to close the `InputStreamReader` themselves...`try (InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(...); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (is)) {...}`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#close-- : Description copied from class: Reader
Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it

Comment: Thank you for you help. After checking about it, I found that you have taught me a useful function in java 1.7. All the elements in parentheses  the should implement java.lang.AutoCloseable.